# I want to write a constant string to a file with the other block of entered data

Tags: c++, string

I want to write a constant string to a text file. I know it can be done by using put-to `operator(<<)`, but I want to write that constant string in the block of data entered through `cin`, `gets`, etc. I need it for my school project. Please be nice and help me out.  If the question isn't clear to you, let me know.

```
cout<<"Enter your name";
gets(name);
cout<<"Enter your roll number";
cin>>rollno;
char string[]="Student of XYZ School";
fout.write((char*)&student,size(student));
```

Note that char string can't be written with other data entered, but I want it to be written in the file with other data only.

Comment: Ugh ugh ugh. Don’t use `gets` ever. It’s deprecated and extremely unsafe.

Comment: Your question isn't making much sense. Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already done `#include <iostream>`, as you must have, why are you using `gets()` and `write()` and C-style strings? It would be much simpler, since this is C++, to use

```
#include <fstream>

string name;
string rollno;
ofstream outfile;

cout << "Enter your name";
cin >> name;

cout << "Enter your roll number";
cin >> rollno;

string str = "Student of XYZ School";

student.write(outfile);
```

You didn't say what type "student" is. In the example above, I assume that it is its own class. If it is, then you can define a member function for it

```
Student::write(ofstream &outfile) {

  outfile << "blah blah blah";
  // etc.
}
```

Whatever you do, DO NOT keep gets() in your program: it leaves your program open to a buffer overflow attack. If you can use cout, you can use cin.